# Too many output arguments from Matlab to C#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I am running a Matlab function from a C# application. I want my Matlab function to return a value to my c# application.

However I get the error message below. I am confused because I am only expecting one value so not sure why this error message it telling me?

> Error using someFunction
>   Too many output arguments.

**Matlab**

```matlab
  function [success] = autoRun_someFunction

  try
     someFunction;
     success = 1;
  catch ME
     success = getReport(ME, 'extended');
  end
```

**c#**

FunctionName = "autoRun_someFunction";

```cs
 public string RunMatlabScriptResult(string FunctionDirectory, string FunctionName)
        {
                // create matlab instance
                _matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

                // change to the directory where the function is located            
                string pathChecker = @"C:\MyFolder\";

                _matlab.Execute(@"cd " + pathChecker);

                // call the matlab is checking the search path    
                object resultChk = null;
                 _matlab.Feval("check_path", 0, out resultChk);

                // change to the directory where the function is located 
                _matlab.Execute(@"cd " + FunctionDirectory);

                // define the output
                object result = null;

                // call the matlab function upload_data                                
                _matlab.Feval(FunctionName, 1, out result);

                // quit matlab
                _matlab.Quit();

                // display result
                object[] res = result as object[];
                return res[0].ToString();                
        }
```

Comment: Which .net framework you use ? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91698-why-do-i-get-the-error-too-many-output-arguments-when-passing-mwchararray-with-matlab-builder-for

Comment: 4.5 is the framework I'm using

Comment: Your C# function is not complete, you don’t show what each variable is set as. I presume `FunctionName` is `autoRun_someFunction`? If so, and you get the error you show, then you should get the same error calling `autoRun_someFunction` from within MATLAB. Did you try that?

Comment: Ah apologies. Yes you are correct FunctionName is autoRun_someFunction. I run the autoRun_someFunction in Matlab and it returns success = 1.

Comment: It is strange I have the same pattern (exactly the same) for another function and it runs fine